# passing a list of data from one intent to another using serializable

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I would like to parse a list of data from one intent to another intent

However, with my code,
I'm only manage to pass the first item in the listview .
I use a log.d to check for the items, and realised that only one items is being pass.
In my listview there's 2 items,when I pass it over to my next intent, only one item was shown in the log..

I did a  serializable in my class.
I make a log in my summary,
however,
when I click on summary, the log that was shown in not all the data.

logcat:

```
01-28 18:20:49.218: D/Bundle(20278): bundle : Bundle[{clickedpreOdometer=, clickedID=2, clickedCost= 12.0, clickedDate=27/12/2014, pojoArrayList=[com.example.fuellogproject.fuelLogPojo@43bf3f18, com.example.fuellogproject.fuelLogPojo@43bf5b68], clickedPump=3, clickedPrice=4, clickedFCon= 0.0, clickedOdometer=3}]
```

listview

```
    public void summaryClick (View v)
{
    Intent sum = new Intent(this, summary.class);
    fuelLogPojo clickedObject = pojoArrayList.get(0);
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("clickedID", clickedObject.getid());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedDate", clickedObject.getdate());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPrice", clickedObject.getprice());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPump", clickedObject.getpump());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedCost", clickedObject.getcost());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedOdometer", clickedObject.getodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedpreOdometer",
            clickedObject.getpreodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedFCon", clickedObject.getfcon());
    dataBundle.putSerializable("pojoArrayList", pojoArrayList);

    Log.i("FuelLog", "dataBundle " + dataBundle);
    // Attach the bundled data to the intent
//  sum.putExtras(dataBundle);
    sum.putExtras(dataBundle);
    Log.i("Exrrass", "dataBundle " + dataBundle);
    // Start the Activity
    startActivity(sum);


}
```

summary.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summary);
        //month = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.month);
        avgPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showavfPriceTV);
        exFuel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showexFuelTV);
        avgFC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showavgFCTV);
        doneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBTN);
        exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitBTN);

        Bundle takeBundledData = getIntent().getExtras();  
        // First we need to get the bundle data that pass from the UndergraduateListActivity

        bundleID = takeBundledData.getString("clickedID");
        /*bundleDate = takeBundledData.getString("clickedDate");
        bundlePrice = takeBundledData.getString("clickedPrice");
        bundlePump = takeBundledData.getString("clickedPump");
        bundleCost = takeBundledData.getString("clickedCost");
        bundleOdometer = takeBundledData.getString("clickedOdometer");
        bundlePreOdometer = takeBundledData.getString("clickedpreOdometer");
        bundleFcon = takeBundledData.getString("clickedFCon");*/
        Log.d("Bundle","bundle : "+ takeBundledData);


}
```

fuelLogpojo.java

```
public class fuelLogPojo implements Serializable{
```

Comment: You may be better off making your objects implement the `Parcelable` interface that way you can just pass the whole object instead of 5 or 6 lines of data each time.

Answer (score 2):

`fuelLogPojo` should implement either `Parcelable` or `Serializable`

Bundles can accept custom classes, if they implement either `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, `Parcelable` is faster but more work to implement and `Serializable` is easier to implement, but slower.

I'm going to imagine that `fuelLogPojo extends Serializable` in this example, just because its easier to setup but you should really consider `Parcelable`

Then you can do this:

```
dataBundle.putSerializable("pojoArrayList", pojoArrayList);
sum.setArguments(bundle);
```

[Also, you should reconsider the naming convention for your classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537620/class-name-convention-in-java)

EDIT:
Here's how to access that `pojoArrayList` in summary.

```
List<fuelLogPojo> pojoArrayList = (List<fuelLogPojo>)extras.getSerializable("pojoArrayList");
```

Comment: I edited the post to include how to access that list in summary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass array of Custom Objects You have to implements `Parcerable` interface

Take a look [here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html)

And then pass array like

```
Intent i=...
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ARRAY", array);
```

and read it

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("ARRAY")
```