# how to set to serialazble with error in setArgument

Tags: android

I would like to make this code at serialazble

But I dk why,
in the setArguments, there is a red underline, thus can't run the code.

Can someone guide me?

```
     public void summaryClick (View v)
{
    Intent sum = new Intent(this, summary.class);
    fuelLogPojo clickedObject = pojoArrayList.get(0);
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("clickedID", clickedObject.getid());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedDate", clickedObject.getdate());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPrice", clickedObject.getprice());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPump", clickedObject.getpump());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedCost", clickedObject.getcost());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedOdometer", clickedObject.getodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedpreOdometer",
            clickedObject.getpreodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedFCon", clickedObject.getfcon());
    dataBundle.putSerializable("pojoArrayList", pojoArrayList);

    Log.i("FuelLog", "dataBundle " + dataBundle);
    // Attach the bundled data to the intent
//  sum.putExtras(dataBundle);
    sum.setArguments(dataBundle);
    // Start the Activity
    startActivity(sum);


}
```

take reference from here
[passing a list of data from one intent to another using serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383772/passing-a-list-of-data-from-one-intent-to-another/21383948?noredirect=1#21383948)

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Serious? just change sum.setArguments(bundle); to sum.setArguments(dataBundle);   :)

Comment: @Niko there is a redline over the over the word setArguements. I hover over it, and was told to add cast to sum.I've follow the instruction, but still redline

Comment: @alex opps, i forgotten to change . However ,after I change back ,it still have redline on the setArguments

Answer (score 3):

`Intent` class has no `setArguments` function on android.

Check this on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: @Chloe Test `putExtras`, maybe it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare any variable as `bundle`. Your `Bundle` is called `dataBundle`.

Change this line:

```
sum.setArguments(bundle);
```

to:

```
sum.putExtra("my data bundle", dataBundle);
```

Comment: I've changed, but there's a red line over setARguments

Comment: I can't run the project, because it contains error. Like I say, there's a red line over the word setARgument that don't allow me to run the project

Comment: as AdolAurion says, there is no such method. I checked the API and edit my answer. Try this and tell me if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think an Intent (sum here) has a method "setArguments"?
So far as i know the setArgument is a method of "Fragment".
If you want to set bundle into an Intent, try "putExtras".

Answer (score 0):

Replace the red line with this:

```
sum.putExtras(dataBundle);
```

Intent does'nt have a function called `setArguments(Bundle bundle)`. Have a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

For a complete example, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821596/1965084) post.